# Finding the zeroes of a sine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$0.09567\cdot\sin( \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}\cdot x) + 0.23096\cdot\sin( \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}\cdot x) = 0$$

How can I calculate the values of $x$ which satisfy this equation? If numerical methods must be used, what are they?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a inifinite number of roots, whatever mnumerical method you plan to use, you will a "reasonable" estimate.

For example, graphing the function, you will notice that the first solutions are located "close" to $$(2,3,5,9,10,12,14,15,17,\cdots)$$

Newton method is the simplest. Let us try it for the root which is close to $14$. The method will give as iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 14.00000000 \\
 1 & 13.78687645 \\
 2 & 13.81098880 \\
 3 & 13.81116777 \\
 4 & 13.81116778
\end{array}
\right)$$